# Cascade Nullify EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm attempting to have the following behavior:

I have a model A and a model B. A has one B. If A is deleted, B should remain unaffected. If B is deleted, A should be nullified. I've tried the below but i'm not sure it does what I need it to. I'm new to .net Core syntax and likely have this way off syntactically.

```
builder.Entity<A>()
.HasOne(a => a.B)
.WithMany(b => b.As)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restricted);

builder.Entity<B>()
.HasMany(b => b.As)
.WithOne(a => a.B)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

Comment: You're configuring the same 1-many relationship in two different ways there.  The OnDelete behviour oin a 1-many refers to a delete of the entity on the 1 side.  Deletes of A would never have any effect on a B.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft So that's what I want then yes? Deletes of A don't affect anything, but deletes of B would nullify the id in A?